# Unique user signature

Tags: php

I need to be able to detect if a used already visited a particular page.

I can set a cookies at their initial visit. I can also store some environment, such as IP, browser, OS, perhaps even language and create some string, like MD5 to compare against current visitor's environment.

Is there another method I should consider?

I work with PHP.

Comment: Anonymous users or Registered users?

Comment: Both, but for registered all I need to do is to check if they are logged in and if the ID is already in my db for that task.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't well defined enough for me to understand why just using cookies wouldn't satisfy this problem.  A cookie has a domain and path that you can set on the server for each page they visit.  As they visit each page you can look at those two settings to figure out if they have the cookie set on their browser or not and hence they have visited the page.  You really don't have to get anymore sophisticated than that if all you want to know is did they visit the page before now.

Comment: It is too easy to circumvent that check. My browser is set to clear all cookies on close, for example.

Comment: So what?  Lots of sites don't continue to track if you clear your cookies.  Is that a requirement?  It wasn't stated in your initial question.

Comment: I need this functionality on the page that collects test data and to keep this data more accurate I need to prevent multiple participation.

Comment: @santa: Without requiring the user to be logged in, there is no foolproof tracking method. Anything you use to track them can and will be cleared.

Comment: I realize that and I would attempt to provide incentives to create a free account or login but at the same time I do not wish to run a risk of alienating some willing participants that might not be interested unless it is anonymous.

Comment: Well then you do the best you can do.  No scheme is foolproof.  You can use cookies, and then try a scheme to match them up to a profile if they remove their cookies by gathering other information that they send to you through their browser using a fuzzy matching algorithm. IP address, browser, language, but really that's not going to be very reliable given DHCP, multiple access devices (smartphone, laptop, etc), multiple browsers. What happens when you guess wrong and assign someone's profile to the wrong person?  In the end you need the user's cooperation in order to do it properly.